# SQL Daily rolling sales last 28 days

Tags: sql, powerpivot

I'm having trouble calculating the rolling sales, I've tried with powerpivot but due the amount of transactions my PC crashes, so I need to do with the source query in SQL Server.

I need a new column by each day with the sum of sales for the last 28 days, I have a daily transaction of sales by item store.

Hope someone help me, thanks.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqeSe.png)

Thanks so much,
JR

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm not sure exactly what the problem is that you're trying to solve based on what you posted. It might be worth reviewing this [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It looks like [this DBA.StackExchange post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107485/rolling-sum-count-average-over-date-interval) might point you in the right direction. I'd also look at making a daily total first, then making your rolling total from that.

Comment: You can use either a window frame on `sum() over ()` or just a scalar subquery.

Answer (score 1):

If you have data for every day, then use window fucntions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(qty) over (partition by store, item order by daily rows between 27 preceding and current row) as avg_28day
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to sum up `Pos Qty` grouped by day and by `Item Nbr` and that you want to have 28 different columns for the 28 last days, your query could look like this:

```
select [Store...], [Item Nbr], 
       sum(case when cast([Daily] as date) = cast(getdate() as date) then [POS Qty] end) SumDay0,
       sum(case when cast([Daily] as date) = cast(getdate() - 1 as date) then [POS Qty] end) SumDay_1,
       sum(case when cast([Daily] as date) = cast(getdate() - 2 as date) then [POS Qty] end) SumDay_2,
       sum(case when cast([Daily] as date) = cast(getdate() - 3 as date) then [POS Qty] end) SumDay_3,
       --...
       sum(case when cast([Daily] as date) = cast(getdate() - 27 as date) then [POS Qty] end) SumDay_27
 from [your table]
group by [Store...], [Item Nbr]
```

This query uses for every sum a `case when` statement in order to filter data just for one of the days you are looking at. Then the result of the the `case when` statement is summed up.

Of course if you'd rather have your result in rows instead of columns then the query needs to be written differently.